# Is there a way to rebuild valid HTML structure from a fragment?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, browser

Suppose you have only `<td>text<td></tr>`. Obviously taken alone it won't be valid (and neither solely `<td>...</td>` will be). Is there an easy way to rebuild valid html structure from such fragment? Which should be something like this: `<table><tbody><tr><td>text<td></tr></tbody></table>`.

Comment: Just add the elements??

Comment: It's not only about TDs or TRs, it's also about LIs and DTs, etc. I know I can write parser with maps and hierarchies. I'm asking if there is an easier way. Some native browser method maybe.

Comment: Not without writing your own function to do so (which, given the various edge cases, is unlikely to qualify as "easy").

Comment: For example if you retrieve the range from selection and it's not valid (incomplete) browser will fill it with absent elements automatically. So the functionality is in there.

Comment: None of the popular browser has such functionality at present. Most you can do is to use an intelligent IDE like Visual Studio that will do about half the work i.e. If you write <table> it will insert </table>

Comment: If I use your example `<td>text<td></tr>` then Chrome does not fill in the missing elements.

Comment: Ok, it seems that it should be in the DOM first and probably range cycles over the dom to rebuild the structure. Hm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`insertAdjacentHTML` seems to do the Right Thing(tm), that is invoking the fragment parsing algorithm that takes context into account.

```
table = document.createElement("table")
table.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<table><tbody><tr><td>Case A</td></tr></tbody></table>")
table.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<td>Case B</td>")

console.log(table.outerHTML)

/*
<table><tbody><tr><td>Case A</td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td>Case B</td></tr></tbody></table>
*/
```

Comment: Nice one! Although my problem is that script is kind of not aware what the required parent  (or common root) of current element should be. And if you do not create 'table' first and start with a 'div' for example, then table.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<td>Case B</td>") won't insert any tds, or trs.

Comment: However I guess this is as close as it can get with native methods. So you take this question :)